# how to create a filepath from an attribute

Tags: javascript, css, xml

I have an xml file which I am trying to transform by using css.

> Part of the xml file:

```
<figure id="fig-0001">
<title>This is a figure</title>
<graphic infoEntityIdent="IMG-001-01"/></figure>
```

The value of the "infoEntityIdent" attribute is the name of an image file (without the filetype extension) that is located in the same directory as the xml file.
If I don't specify the file extension like below:

```
 graphic
    {
        content: url(IMG-001-01);
    }
```

the image is not displayed.

> It works when I type it like this:

```
 graphic
    {
        content: url(IMG-001-01.png);
    }
```

How can I get the image to be displayed? Can I get it to be displayed with javascript?

My limitations are:

- I cannot manipulate the xml file itself (cannot add the file extension manually to the end of the attribute value)
- The image files are not same type (mixed type of *.jpeg, *png etc.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or plunker, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an in-memory, img element, and load both the url variations (png and jpg), in succession, whichever loads successfully, can be used. You can use code similar to following jquery code for this.

```
$(graphic).forEach((gr)=>{
         $("<img/>")
        .on('load', function() { console.log("image loaded correctly"); })
        .on('error', function() { 
                $(this).attr("src", $(gr).attr("infoEntityIdent")+".png");
        })
        .attr("src", $(gr).attr("infoEntityIdent")+".jpg")
    ;
    });
```

Or with css, you can use 2 psedo elements after and before, whichever loads will show up.

```
graphic:after
    {
        content: url(IMG-001-01) ".png";
    }
graphic:before
    {
        content: url(IMG-001-01) ".jpg";
    }
```